# Count the number of records grouped by 1 hour increments on the half hour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, count

We have a management dashboard that needs to display the number of products produced per hour.  My problem is our production hours run on the half hour.  For example:

```
DayShift Production hour #1 runs from 7:30am to 8:30am
DayShift Production hour #2 runs from 8:30am to 9:30am
DayShift Production hour #3 runs from 9:30am to 10:30am
DayShift Production hour #4 runs from 10:30am to 11:30am
DayShift Production hour #5 runs from 11:30am to 12:30pm
DayShift Production hour #6 runs from 12:30pm to 1:30pm
DayShift Production hour #7 runs from 1:30pm to 2:30pm
DayShift Production hour #8 runs from 2:30pm to 3:30pm
DayShift Production hour #9 runs from 3:30pm to 4:30pm
DayShift Production hour #10 runs from 4:30pm to 5:30pm
```

And then it gets really confusing for our nightshift...

```
Nightshift Production hour #1 runs from 8:30pm to 9:30pm
Nightshift Production hour #2 runs from 9:30pm to 10:30pm
Nightshift Production hour #3 runs from 10:30pm to 11:30pm
Nightshift Production hour #4 runs from 11:30pm to 12:30am
Nightshift Production hour #5 runs from 12:30am to 1:30am
Nightshift Production hour #6 runs from 1:30am to 2:30am
Nightshift Production hour #7 runs from 2:30am to 3:30am
Nightshift Production hour #8 runs from 3:30am to 4:30am
Nightshift Production hour #9 runs from 4:30am to 5:30am
Nightshift Production hour #10 runs from 5:30am to 6:30am
```

My table looks like this:

```
recordnbr (identity) int
PartNbr varchar(50)
crtdDateTime datetime
```

My output should look like this:

```
7:30am - 50
8:30am - 49
9:30am - 53
10:30am - 55
11:30am - 48
```

etc.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subtract 30 mins and use the built in hour function.
Like this

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95164c/4)**

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(mi,-30, dt)) as VARCHAR(5))+':30', count(*)
FROM dtime
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(mi,-30, dt))
```

Remember, you need to limit to a single day or include DATE(crtdDateTime) in the GROUP BY

Comment: can you explain what happen there?

Comment: what happen with `Nightshift Production hour #4 runs from 11:30pm to 12:30am`

Comment: Counted for the prior day

Comment: I think will work, and dont think you need the limit to one day. Because even in a range you get the group by hour just fine. Looks like op want total of products on each slot .

Comment: I still not see why you say need limit to one day

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza because if you don't limit to the day then you are counting every days hour range not just the one you are interested in.... but try it and see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I kind of have the same question.  On my nightshift, obviously the production times span 2 days (cross over midnight).  How can I handle that if I limit to a single day?

Comment: @DaleKelsey The way to thank someone for their answer on Stack Overflow is to upvote their answer.   
The way I would deal with overnight is to do another timeshift in the where clause so that if overnight counts on the next day then do something like `WHERE DATEADD(hours,3.5, dt)  = targetdate`

Answer (score 0):

create a table `hour_range`

```
 hour_id  start    end
   1      7:30am   8:30am
   2      8:30am   9:30am
   3      9:30am   10:30am
   .....
   18     11:30pm   12:00am 
   18     12:00am   12:30am        
   .....
   25     6:30am   7:30am
```

Then

```
SELECT hour_id, count(*)
FROM myTable M
JOIN hour_range H
  ON cast(M.crtdDateTime as time) >= H.start
 AND cast(M.crtdDateTime as time) <  H.end
GROUP BY hour_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Can you explain how this would handle the roll over on nightshift at midnight?

Comment: I put two rows `18` for midnight.